# IIS 7 Satisfy Google If-Modified-Since HTTP header Requirement

Tags: c#, iis-7, umbraco

From Google

> Make sure your web server supports the If-Modified-Since HTTP header.
>   This feature allows your web server to tell Google whether your
>   content has changed since we last crawled your site. Supporting this
>   feature saves you bandwidth and overhead.

We run a Umbraco website and am wondering how to satisfy this requirement, I understand that there is issues with the data been "dynamic" and would like to at least say let it expire after 1 day.

This my client and her SEO representative feels is important due to the last Google update.

Thanks in advance guys!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't related directly to Umbraco but rather more general description of how I solved a similar situation.

I first made sure that a LastModified/LastUpdated field exist in the database and that it's being updated when ever a post is inserted or updated. I then send it to the client using the Last-Modified HTTP-Header.

When the client then requests the same page again, and sends the If-Modified-Since header, I look at the date it sent. Compared it to the value in the database. If it's the same I returned a Status 304 Not Modified to the client and stopped execution of the ASP.NET code.

If the values where different, I load the page as usual.

So basicly all I had to do was to was to send a Modified-Since header to the client, read the If-Modified-Since header from the client and do one extra if on that value. This should be possible to do in Umbraco, but since I don't run it myself I can't tell you exactly where to do the changes.